# Ideas for launching an installed app from a webpage

Tags: security, web-applications, architecture, user-interface

I am thinking about having the following use-case:

1. User installs application on local machine.
2. User goes to our website, and are presented with many links (choices).
3. User clicks on a link.
4. Application starts, with some information contained within the link passed to the application.

Step 4 is obviously a security minefield. The end goal is that the user makes a choice, and if the application is installed, it starts with some information passed to it (ie command line parameters, or perhaps a temp file somewhere on the user's machine)

Can I/ Should I access the registry from javascript? Are there any ideas about how I might go about this? Do you have an alternative suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the applications the user installs are also developed by you.

Register a file extension for use by the specific application - then your web links can be links to a file that is downloaded and auto-run by your app.  The file could contain details on the defaults for your app to use.

Sort of like how clicking on a .pdf file opens your pdf reader.

Comment: This was my first guess. I'm starting to think this is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the file-extension solution you may want to know about [Custom Application Protocol feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx). Link is for Windows but there are nearly same techniques on other systems. I can't say if this approach works in every browser but you may want to try it out.

Comment: This looks very interesting, thank you. I'm worried about the amount of configuration I need to do with respect to the registry. I would need a different protocol for each product, and there are several at the moment, but later there could be a dozen or more.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the registry from JavaScript inside a browser is nigh on impossible for the security implications. To access the registry from the web, I'd imagine you'd have to use a binary (C++ or others) program that can read the registry, but also has an HTTP module to communicate with your server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need the Click Once deployement feature for your app. I think once it's installed over http there should be a pretty easy way to launch an executable.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce

Comment: The application is already installed. I simply want to launch it.